# I'm trying to factory reset a phone. How do I erase "downloaded SIMs"?

Tags: factory-reset, google-pixel, esim

I have Google Pixel. When trying to factory reset it, it says "downloaded SIMs may remain on the device".

What does that mean? How do I erase these data?

Answer (score 1):

The "downloaded SIMs" here refers to [embedded-SIMs (eSIMs)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ESIM).

According to [the AOSP source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Settings/+/master/res/values/strings.xml), looks like the error message happens when the Factory Data Reset fails to erase eSIM data.

> ```
> <!-- Factory data reset erase eSIM failure text [CHAR LIMIT=none] -->
> <string name="fdr_esim_failure_text">Please reboot the device and try again. If you continue factory reset, the downloaded SIMs may remain on the device.</string>
> ```

To erase eSIM data, try resetting the network settings first. For [Google Pixel series](https://support.google.com/pixelphone/answer/2926415),

> **Tip**: To reset all your network settings, in your phone’s Settings app, tap **System** [image: And then] **Advanced** [image: And then] **Reset options** [image: And then] **Reset Wi-Fi, mobile & Bluetooth**.

Otherwise, to retain eSIM data through the Factory Data Reset, it should be possible to just continue the process when prompted.